# ColdFusion restful web services URI

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

What I am trying to do is set up a service that works like this.

`http://server.com/html/print/helloworld`

and get an html page response like this

```
<html>

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
         <p>helloworld</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

then write another component that works like this.

`http://server.com/json/print/helloworld`

so that I get a response that looks like this

```
{"helloworld"}
```

I think what I want to do is intercept the URI, parse it, and return the information. Could someone please set me straight.

Comment: Do you intend to have server.com/index.cfm doing all of this? or server.com/html/print/index.cfm handle the print and server.com/json/print/index.cfm handle the json?  both options are feasible, but i'm unclear on which approach you are thinking of.

Comment: @MattH. Ahh my mistake, I had intended server.com/index.cfm to handle everything.

Answer (score 3):

Henry is correct. I just want to mention couple of more frameworks:

- http://taffy.riaforge.org/
- http://coldbox.org

I have used extensively and thus far is my favorite framework for RESTful services.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using ColdFusion 10 (in public beta as of now) if you want to implement RESTful Services.

http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/introduction-to-restful-webservices-in-coldfusion-10

Otherwise, your only option would be using some RESTful style frameworks for CF8/9.  AFAIK none of them are wildly used...

http://fusiongrokker.com/post/taffy-a-restful-framework-for-coldfusion

http://powernap.riaforge.org/

http://quicksilver.riaforge.org/

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, both those options are off the table. Oh well.